# 'curl localhost:3000/block/1' got error 'curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer'

Tags: curl

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9QhY.png)
this is result of 'docker-compose up'

but i got error 'curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer' when use 'curl localhost:3000/block/1'

Comment: What happens if you google "docker port connection reset by peer" ?

Comment: @mxito3 yapie - Were you able to resolved this issue ?